# Weird character when php file is embeded in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, character

I'm encountering a problem with displaying content of a php file via jquery. The content is http://pastebin.com/V8RxqPe3

Here is my problem:
If that content is in a mysql database, `content.php` file query to get that content and echo it. When i open localhost/content.php, everything is fine. But if i display the content via jquery (below), i got some black question marks (weird character).

```
<div id="results"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $.get('http://localhost/content.php', function(data) {
             $('#results').html(data);
         });
     });
</script>
```

When i manually replace all `'` with `\'` and put the entire content into a variable in the `content.php` file, then echo that variable via the same jquery script above, everything is fine.

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve the problem?, Since i have a lot of that kind of content in my database that i want to display via the above jquery script.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your page and mysql connection set to utf-8 ?

Comment: Be careful: your "test" escaping with `\'` happens in a PHP literal, so it may (or may not) do what you believe. Look for encoding problems first: do you set the proper content-type? + @vodich's suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, problem is solved by adding the line `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);`. Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer if you think it helped upvote please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your page AND mysql connection set to utf-8 ?